# I am trying to program a "robot" waiter program but I can't seem to find where I went wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program has errors and bugs that I need to fix. It's about a "robot" that is a waiter in a restaurant. I am still a beginner.

I tried looking through my program for the bugs and tried indenting and dedenting different parts of my program to try and get it working. I als o tried messing around with the operators but nothing seems to work.

```
import sys, time
total = 0
menu = ["0 - Swedish Meatballs - 5$", "1 - Japanese Sushi - 7$", "2 - Indian Rice - 9$", "3 - Quit"]
price = [5,7,9,0]
print("Hello welcome to the restaurant! I am your robotic waiter")
action = int(input("What would you like to do? \n 1. Look at the menu \n 2. Order \n 3. Take more time \n 4. Ask for the total \n 5. Exit \n Please enter a number here: "))
while action != 5:
        if action == 1:
                print(menu)
                action = int(input("What would you like to do? \n 1. Look at the menu \n 2. Order \n 3. Take more time \n 4. Ask for the total \n 5. Exit \n Please enter a number here: "))
        elif action == 2:
                print(menu)
                food = int(input("What would you like? "))
                while food != 3:
                        priceoffood = price[food]
                        total = total + priceoffood
                        if food != 3:
                                more = input("More things? Reply with y or n: ")
                                if more == "y":
                                        print(menu)
                                        food = int(input("What would you like? "))
                                        if priceoffood != 3:
                                                print(food)
                                                print(price[food])
                                                priceoffood = price[food]
                                                total = total + priceoffood
                        else:
                                break
        elif action == 3:
                time = int(input("How many minutes more do you need?  "))
                while int(time) > 30:
                        print ("Isn't that too long? ")
                        time = input("How many minutes more do you need?  ")
                print("Okay, ill be back when your " + str(time) + " minutes are over!")
                time.sleep(time*60)
        elif action == 4:
                print("Your total is: " + str(total))
quit()
```

I would like the menu functions to be working just like how they are expected to be.

Comment: Others reading your post cannot magically know what your program is supposed to output. Please include any errors in your post and identify specific issues within the program.

Comment: My problem starts line 11 till line 18. I would like my program here to ask the user what they would like out of the menu, get the price of that food, ask them again if they want more food, then calculate a total for the bill. That's basically it.

Comment: Please don't change your code after asking your question, especially if you try to correct it according to the comments/answers you got: that renders the answers irrelevant to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You imported `time`, but also used it as a variable. Change your variable to something other than time. For example:

```
timer = int(input("How many minutes more do you need?  "))
while int(timer) > 30:
    print ("Isn't that too long? ")
    timer = input("How many minutes more do you need?  ")
print("Okay, ill be back when your " + str(timer) + " minutes are over!")
time.sleep(timer*60)
```